# React - Fall back to the initial data (raw data before any input) when submission failed in a controlled form

Tags: reactjs

I need the input values to be the original data as the initial render (like default values)

If using uncontrolled form this could be easy but I need some features like immediate validation coming with controlled form.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { input: 'INITIALDATA' } // Data fetched at componentDidMount
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch and set the initial data
  }
  
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }
  
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('afakewebsiteofcourse.com', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.input)
    }).then(res => {
      // Won't ever be successful in this example
      this.setState({ input: res.json() });
    }).catch(e => {
      /* Fall back to the initial data fetched?

      */
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you say initial data, you mean the absolute initial state that was declared and not the second last data? I mean It could be that the `handleChange` had been called multiple times, what would you want in that case?

Comment: Would you still want the `INITIAL DATA` in that case too?

Comment: When submission failed I need all the input values to be as they were initialized once componentDidMount

Comment: Can you check my answer and see if that's what you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, maybe this would help!

Major changes to see are in `constructor`, `componentDidMount` and `catch` of `handleSubmit`.

What I did:

- Set a class member `initialState` to the fetched intial data
- Reset the classes `state` to the `initialState` using `this.setState` when an error is catched in `fetch(...).catch`

```
    class Form extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { input: 'INITIALDATA' } // Data fetched at componentDidMount
        this.initialState = this.state;
      }
      
      componentDidMount() {
        // fetch and set the initial data
        // or if you fetch the initial data here, then set it to this.intialState
        // after fetching
        fetchInitialData().then(res => this.initialState = res);
      }
      ......
      ......
      handleSubmit = e => {
        ......
        ......
        }).then(res => {
          // Normal maneuver if success
          this.setState({ input: res.json() });
        }).catch(e => {
          /* Fall back to the initial data fetched!
          */
    
          this.setState(this.initialState);
        })
      }
      
      render() {
        ......
        ......
      }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Form/>, document.body)
```

Comment: But you are still rendering with data from `this.state`. Where do you refer your `initialState`?

Comment: You should always render data from the `this.state`, however I am updating the state with the `intialState` when an error is catched. The initial state is intialized with the initial data in `componentDidMount`!